# How do I replace an underscore "_" to a "/" using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

It is possible to replace the underscore "_" to a "/" using htaccess?
Example, I want this
http://example.com/empresa_historia-da-empresa.php
Stay well
http://example.com/empresa/historia-da-empresa

Is it possible?

Comment: If you have access to httpd.conf it's easier to use a RewriteMap to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=4]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1/$2/$3/$4/$5 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1/$2/$3/$4 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1/$2/$3 [E=uscor:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1/$2 [E=uscor:Yes]

RewriteCond %{ENV:uscor} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Found here (and changed a bit): http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html#Rewrite_underscores_hyphens_SEO_URL
It will work for 1 to 4 underscroes

Comment: Will actually work for up to 10 underscores. As the the first rule replaces the first four it finds. But then the second one is executed which replace the next 3 underscores, etc. And even if there are more that 10 apache will keep removing 10 underscores and redirecting, until there are no more left.

Comment: You are right, this works for up to 10 underscores. But if I use 11, the URL "a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k_l.php" is redirected to "a/b/c/d/e/f/o/h/i/j/k/l.php/b/c/d/e/f/o/h/i/j/k/l.php/b/c/d/e/f/o/h/i/j/k/l.php/b/c/d/e/f/o..." the URL does not end, so the browser displays a 414-error.

Comment: You might be right there. Possibly adding the `L` flag on all rewriterules would solve this.

Comment: That's interesting. If I change "_" to "-", everything is working fine (even without the L-flag). But "_" to "/" creates this error as soon as I use more than 10 underscores. It also does not help to add the L-flag.